# Virtualbox error when updating my computer

Tags: apt, virtualbox

I am getting this error whenever try to update my computer "An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian jammy InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY A2F683C52980AECF "

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I fix the GPG error "NO\_PUBKEY"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13065/how-do-i-fix-the-gpg-error-no-pubkey)

Answer (score -1):

remove that repo, Open the Software & Updates application Other Software then press remove, because virtualbox is in the native repos since focal